# Rails whenever gem giving error when deploying via capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cron, whenever, whenever-capistrano

I'm trying to create my first cron job via the whenever gem for a rails project. When running `cap deploy`, i get this error:

```
...
* 2013-01-01 22:29:00 executing `whenever:update_crontab'
  * executing "cd /var/www/vhosts/famnfo.com/releases/20130102042834 && bundle exec whenever --update-crontab FamNFo --set environment=production --roles db"
    servers: ["famnfo.com"]
    [famnfo.com] executing command
 ** [out :: famnfo.com] /var/www/vhosts/famnfo.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb:49:in `days': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
 ** [out :: famnfo.com] from config/schedule.rb:23:in `initialize'
 ** [out :: famnfo.com] from /var/www/vhosts/famnfo.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/whenever-0.8.1/lib/whenever/job_list.rb:25:in `instance_eval'
 ** [out :: famnfo.com] from /var/www/vhosts/famnfo.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/whenever-0.8.1/lib/whenever/job_list.rb:25:in `initialize'
 ** [out :: famnfo.com] from /var/www/vhosts/famnfo.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/whenever-0.8.1/lib/whenever.rb:15:in `new'
 ** [out :: famnfo.com] from /var/www/vhosts/famnfo.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/whenever-0.8.1/lib/whenever.rb:15:in `cron'
 ** [out :: famnfo.com] from /var/www/vhosts/famnfo.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/whenever-0.8.1/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:55:in `whenever_cron'
 ** [out :: famnfo.com] from /var/www/vhosts/famnfo.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/whenever-0.8.1/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:106:in `updated_crontab'
 ** [out :: famnfo.com] from /var/www/vhosts/famnfo.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/whenever-0.8.1/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:36:in `run'
 ** [out :: famnfo.com] from /var/www/vhosts/famnfo.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/whenever-0.8.1/lib/whenever/command_line.rb:7:in `execute'
 ** [out :: famnfo.com] from /var/www/vhosts/famnfo.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/whenever-0.8.1/bin/whenever:41:in `<top (required)>'
 ** [out :: famnfo.com] from /var/www/vhosts/famnfo.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/whenever:19:in `load'
 ** [out :: famnfo.com] from /var/www/vhosts/famnfo.com/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/whenever:19:in `<main>'
    command finished in 2308ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
...
```

Here's my schedule.rb code:

```
set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log"

every 1.day :at => "8:00am" do
    runner "BirthdayReminders.send_birthday_email_reminders"
end
```

I've added this to my capistrano deploy.rb file

```
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
require "whenever/capistrano"
```

Comment: what is on this line? `from config/schedule.rb:23:in `initialize'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log"

every 1.day :at => "8:00am" do
    runner "BirthdayReminders.send_birthday_email_reminders"
end
```

Try adding a comma after day:

```
every 1.day, :at => "8:00am" do
  ...
```

Comment: Ahh on second thought the comma does fix it. I hadn't commited my code after adding the comma so `cap deploy` didn't pick it up.